# What is the cookieJar?

Tags: php, buzz

What is the cookie Jar class from Buzz used for?

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Cookie/Jar.php

For example when I'm making a request:

```
$browser = new Buzz\Browser();
$response = $browser->get('http://www.google.com');
```

How should i use the cookie thingy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies for your requests are stored in there. If you want to keep them you have to persist this cookie jar.

Comment: so if I make a request, I will get all my cookies from that request there?

Comment: @Ella yeah, all cookies will be stored there

Comment: I see that only the "FileGetContents" client has this cookie jar, the "Curl" client doesn't :s

Comment: @Ella if you need this functionality you should either write an wishlist-issue to the buzz author or rewrite the Curl wrapper to your needs